# Linkage - Create Even Sized Clusters?

Tags: clustering, python, hierarchical-clustering, scipy

I want to cluster some data points into a given number of clusters according to their nearest neighbour, but with a preference towards even sized clusters when there are multiple pairs with the same distance.

I have tried using `linkage` from `fastcluster` (`scipy.cluster.hierarchy` behaves the same) to cluster according to the distance matrix (I have pairwise distances, but objects to cluster have no co-ordinates), but with a uniform distance matrix it merges the first two items together, then the third into the same cluster and so forth, generating one big cluster and lots of single items.

I am using a custom bit of code to parse the output matrix from `linkage` and form the `k` clusters. I've tried different `method` and `metric` parameters, but without a strong understanding of them, and with no luck.

I am happy to consider alternative clustering methods, provided I can specify `k`, need only pairwise distance/similarity, and it favours even clustering. I understand that I cannot have perfectly even clusters (nor do I want to), but I do want as even as possible distribution when things are otherwise equal.

There is a Jupyter notebook with a small example case here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/TomAnthony/9b813d68ece7ce1f4daa394df963499c

Thanks!

Comment: You wish simultaneously two almost incompatible things: nearest neighbour link and (approximately) same sized clusters. In real situations with not very much separated clusters you have no chance to succeed at that.

Answer (score 2):

If you desire almost even sized partitions, I would be reluctant to call this "clustering". Because this implies largely ignoring the *structure* of the data set, in favor of breaking it into even sized partitions.

Ties should rarely happen, unless you have a very low data resolution. If this makes a difference, then you probably have data issues.

A simple workaround to try is *shuffle your data* and keep the most even result. But that is quite slow.

It's fairly easy to **modify AGNES** to prefer merging smaller clusters when distances are tied. You simply need a second criterion, cluster size. But I doubt it will make a difference.

You can try [k-means with even sized clusters](https://elki-project.github.io/tutorial/same-size_k_means), available in the "tutorial" package of ELKI (I use the github version, built from source). It works and will find a *local optimum*, but because of the size constraints results are often rather "unintuitive" (and there probably often is no "intuitive" solution with clusters of the same size)